# jQuery Promise is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2013, promise

I'm trying to use jQuery's promise object to ensure my async call is complete before other code runs. I need to use the Deferred object because I am use SharePoint's `executeQueryAsync` to run the query. I am using Shereen Qumsieh's example [here](http://blog.qumsieh.ca/2013/10/31/using-jquery-promises-deferreds-with-sharepoint-2013-jsom/).

My issue is that in the result handler the jQuery promise is always undefined and I cannot determine why. Has anyone experienced this before? Any help or clues to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thanks.

**Query**

```
function successCallback() {
            console.log(this.d.promise());
            this.d.resolve(this.list);
        }

        function failCallback() {
            console.log(this.d.promise());
            this.d.reject("something bad happened");
        }

        function getMyList() {
            var d = jQuery.Deferred();

            console.log(d.promise());

            var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Documents');
            clientContext.load(list);

            var o = {d: d, list:list};
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(o, successCallback), Function.createDelegate(o, failCallback));

            return d.promise();
        }
```

**Result Handler**

```
var result = getMyList();

console.log(result);// output: undefined

        result.done(function(result) { //TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined
            // result is an SP.List because that is what we passed to resolve()!
            var list = result;
            console.log('Result done hit. result: ' + result);
        });
        result.fail(function(result) {
            // result is a string because that is what we passed to reject()!
            var error = result;
            console.log('Result fail hit. result: ' + error);
        });
```

**UPDATES:**

**getMyList console.log(d.promise()) output**

```
Object {state: function, always: function, then: function, promise: function, pipe: function…}
```

**successCallback console.log(this.d.promise()) output**

```
Object {state: function, always: function, then: function, promise: function, pipe: function…}
```

**Result Handler console.log(result) output**

```
undefined
```

**Sequential Output with timestamps**

```
getMyList ln 449 Promise output 1412279244379: [object Object]
getMyList ln 458 Promise output 1412279244390: [object Object]
Result output 1412279244392: undefined
Result Handler Error time: 1412279244392: TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined
successCallback Promise output 1412279244569: [object Object] 
successCallback Resolve output 1412279244570: [object Object]
```

Comment: That's odd. Are you sure that you're calling the right `getList` function? What version of jQuery are you using? Could you please `console.log(d.promise())` inside the `getList` function and show us what it yieldS?

Comment: Sure will do. jQuery version 1.11.1

Comment: Updated Question with `console.log(d.promise());` output. Also, change `getList` to `getMyList` to see if my code still ran and it did.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle showing the problem?

Comment: @DonRhummy I'm not sure if I can. I am using SharePoint API.

Comment: You can create some fake objects/classes with the same Sharepoint APIs (e.g. `var SP = { ClientContext = { get_current: function() { return ... } } };` ) and return what you'd expect to be returned and see if it still gives the same error. This could help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Hm, that looks like a valid promise object. Can you also do `console.log(result)` right after you got it from the `getList()` call, and right before you call the `.done()` method on it? `result` obviously should not be `undefined` so we need to narrow down where the mistake happens.

Comment: Added output of `this.d.promise()` to successCallback

Comment: @DonRhummy How would I mimic `clientContext.executeQueryAsync`?

Comment: If `getMyList()` really looks as you've posted it, and it's really being called as posted, then the variable "result" **cannot** be `undefined`. JavaScript isn't broken.

Comment: What if you step through the `getMyList()` call in the debugger?

Comment: I think `Function.createDelegate()` is some piece of MS/.net nonsense, certainly not native javascript. If you must do it that way (elsewhere, not here), then use the native `.bind()`. But `.bind()` isn't really the solution here. Try moving `successCallback` and `failCallback` *inside* `getMyList() {...}`. And having done so, purge `Function.createDelegate()`, change `this.d` to `d` all through, and delete `o`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure the exact root cause of my issue, but I did find a solution. There were two main differences that enabled the solution. First, I used the `SP.RequestExecutor` instead of `SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync`. Then getting rid of the `Function.createDelegate()` nonsense as @Roamer-1888 suggested. The `SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync` kept returning a `SP.ClientRequest` object that was never actually resolved and the `Function.createDelegate` was doing some weird scoping with the promise object. Still not sure on that one.

```
       var def = new jQuery.Deferred();

        var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl);

        var data = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.ListItemEntityTypeFullName' },"
                + "'Title': '" + Title + "',"
                + "'Body': '" + Body+ "'}";


        executor.executeAsync({
          url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'<enter_guid_here>')/items",
          method: "POST",
          body: data,
          headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
          },
          success: CsomSuccess,
          error: CsomFail
        });


        function CsomSuccess(result){
            def.resolve(result);
        }

        function CsomFail(data, errorCode, errorMessage){
            def.reject('Failed to get host site. Error:' + errorMessage);
        }

        return def.promise();
```

Comment: That's weird. My guess would have been that you had some mismatched braces somewhere so that your `getMyList` function didn't end where you (where we) did think it did; and that you fixed this problem when refactoring.